# Hydra brute-force not working

Tags: brute-force, hydra, dvwa

This is the command I am using and when I press Enter :

```
hydra -L username.txt -P passwords.txt localhost http-post-form "dvwa/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login="Login Failed"
```

>
This arrow shows up and no thing happen. I have no idea what to do. I searched on internet and could not find any help.

Comment: Have you tried something else besides `localhost`? Like the actual URL?

Comment: Yes i used actual ip address but that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not properly escaped the " and they don't match up. What you are seeing is your shell waiting for additional input because the second closing " is missing.

Not that on the [site](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-crack-online-web-form-passwords-with-thc-hydra-burp-suite-0160643/) where you probably got your instructions it looks different:

```
 kali >hydra -L <wordlist> -P<password list>
 192.168.1.101 http-post-form "/dvwa/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Login failed"
```